# Laravel won't create profile table after user registration

Tags: laravel, database, registration, profile, one-to-one

I created the Profile table with 'user details' this table is connected to User. It was working fine till suddenly profile table won't create any rows after registration.
I have checked my code multiple times and I have even compered with my last working git.
The Profile and user classes seem to be fine. I have no errors the page redirect but the profile row is not created has no id. What else can go wrong that the table wont create? How can i debug it?
**Profile class:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
/**
 * Get user age.
 */
public function get_age()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birthdate'])->age;
}

}
```

**User Class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

Profile table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string("user_name")->nullable();
            $table->string("familyname")->nullable();
            $table->string("location")->nullable();
            $table->string("gender")->nullable();
            $table->date("birthdate")->nullable();
            $table->string("favorite_sport")->nullable();
            $table->string("biography")->nullable();
            $table->string("profil_photo")->nullable();
            
            $table->index("user_id");
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

Register controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect(route('profile.edit', $user->username));
    }
}
```

**Profile Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
        /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index( $username )
    {
        return view('profiles.index', [ 'user' => $username ]);    
    }

    public function edit( $username )
    {  
        return view('profiles.edit', [ 'user' => $username ]);    
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
/**
 * Routes User Profile
 */
Route::get('/profiles/{username}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'index'])->name('profile.show');
Route::get('/profiles/{username}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
```

Comment: And how do you expect the Profile model to be created if there is no related code in `create()` method? Did you forget to add some code here?

Comment: There is no code missing. As you see I'm quite new to Laravel. So I don't quite understand all the concepts. I was following this tutorial along [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE&t=314s) repo: [link](https://github.com/coderstape/freeCodeGram) they haven't used create() method either. It's like hasOne and belongsTo did the job (they the use update method though). Where should I place create() method inside RegisterConstroller or User or Profile?

Comment: The table doesn't get created? That should be done in a migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to run

```
php artisan migrate
```

to migrate all your database design to database itself. It is like running sql table create code to your database.

All resource creations must be done by developer. Like inside Register controller's create  method.

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

In the code you see it is returning created User. However, you need to create profile too. If you change your method to this:

```
    $user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->profile()->create(['user_name' => $user->username]);

    return $user;
```

It will create the user and make a related profile record for this user.

Comment: He took copied your answer and accepted his own instead of yours...

Comment: You are right I did not see that. Soon there wont be any body to help these guys.